# Fetch git notes when cloning

Tags: git, git-notes

I know that git notes can be fetched after cloning using:

```
git fetch origin refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
```

or even be setup in git config to be always fetched.

However at clone time I do not get the notes, so I have to clone and then fetch. Although I do see that using `--mirror` when cloning does get notes too. However my optimal setup would be that I could clone any repository without doing a mirror (since it implies `--bare` and would also get other unwanted refs) and get the notes too.

Is there any way to setup for example git config to fetch specific additional refs at clone time ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is "no": at clone time, you have your choice of either cloning with the default refspec (`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/$remote/*`, where `$remote` is replaced with `origin` or the remote name you select) or with the `--mirror` fetch-mirror refspec (`+refs/*:refs/*`).  As you note, `--mirror` implies `--bare`, and is probably not desirable here.

It would be easy enough to write a shell script that does a clone, then does `git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*"`, then runs `git fetch`, so that you need not run three commands yourself.  (Whether you want the `+` here, and/or to rename their notes to some other reference name, is up to you.  For the FreeBSD repository, I use `fetch = +refs/notes/*:refs/notes/origin/*` and set `notesRef = refs/notes/origin/commits`, a practice I copied from elsewhere without thinking about it too much—and so far I have had no reason to rethink or change it.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

I was amazed there's no `git clone --with-notes` that automatically does this.

I should probably submit a patch...

Comment: Some people have mentioned you can pass extra refspecs to `--config` when you clone, but a (known) bug causes clone to ignore them. Haven't tested. Hacky anyway.

Comment: @CraigRinger: that's annoying. Clone has some code to re-read the config file created during the init-and-config steps; I wonder why that doesn't take care of the refspecs. (Clone is essentially a C coded version of "init, then config, then fetch, then checkout".)

Comment: @CraigRinger I am writing to you from the future (2020) and still there is no `git clone --with-notes` :(